# помогите разобраться с функцией split() в jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

выдает typeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'values.split')

но если вместо

```
    function transform(el, prop, values) {
  var propFull = getFullName(prop) || prop;
  $(el).css(propFull, values)
}
```

написать:

```
function transform(el, prop, values) {
  $(el).css(prop, values)
}
```

полностью игнорируя словарь сокращений, который мне очень необходим, то все работает ок.

но я хочу чтобы работало и так, и так. т.е можно было писать значения через запятую, как: `border=2px,solid,black` и чтоб при этом словарь сокращений тоже работал, как: `w=200px h=50px`

полный пример игнорируя словарь:

```js
var slovar = {
  //width and height
  'w': 'width',
  'h': 'height'
}

function getFullName(shortName) {
  return slovar[shortName];
}

function getProp(classStr) {
  return classStr.split('=')[0]
}

function getValues(classStr) {
  var values = classStr.split('=')[1]
  return values.split(',').join(' ')
}

function transform(el, prop, values) {
  var propFull = getFullName(prop) || prop;
  $(el).css(propFull, values)
}



var elements = $('div, p, span, img, li, ul, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')
elements.each(function(i, el) {
  var classList = $(el).attr('class')
  if (!classList) return
  var classProps = classList.split(' ')
  $(classProps).each(function(i, str) {
    var prop = getProp(str)
    var values = getValues(str)
    transform(el, prop, values)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='border=2px,solid,black'>hello world</div>
```

и еще... как мне задать все существующие элементы в переменной `elements`?
не писать же все по одному как в примере.?

Comment: вставлять нужно не кусок кода, который работает, а кусок, который _НЕ_ работает, иначе совсем непонятно, а что, собственно, не так?

Comment: Вообще стоит разбить данный вопрос на 5-6 отдельных конкретных вопросов, а не спрашивать все в одном

Comment: о! я сообразила:D в классах надо сначала писать все свойства которые должны писаться через запятую, а потом уже обычные, без множественных значений.. но все равно, почему именно так? как это возможно исправить, чтобы было можно в любом порядке вставлять??

Comment: Без конкретного примера с ошибкой, нельзя сказать - в чем была ошибка и как ее решить.

Comment: Для начала придумайте четкий разделитель свойств - символ, который не используется в css. Тогда не нужно будет что-то перечислять через запятую.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var slovar = {
  //width and height
  'w': 'width',
  'h': 'height'
}

function getFullName(shortName) {
  return slovar[shortName];
}

function getProp(classStr) {
  return classStr.split('=')[0];
}

function getValues(classStr) {
  return classStr.split('=')[1];
}

function transform(el, prop, values) {
  var newProp = getFullName(prop) || prop;
  $(el).css(newProp, values);
}

var elements = $('div, p, span, img, li, ul, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')
elements.each(function(i, el) {
  var classList = $(el).attr('class');
  if (!classList) return;
  var classProps = classList.split(';');
  $(classProps).each(function(i, str) {
    var prop = getProp(str);
    var values = getValues(str);
    transform(el, prop, values);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='border=2px solid black;w=200px;h=100px'>hello world</div>
```